# How can I take a list of server names and append a resource URI and port to each?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I merged two lists from an Ansible inventory:

```
set_fact:
  fact1: "{{ groups['group1'] + groups[group2']|list }}
```

The output is:

```
fact1:
  - server01
  - server02
  - server03
```

With the above results, I need to append `https://` to the front, and a port number to the back of each element.
Then I need to convert it to a comma delimited list for a server config.

In this example I want: `https://server01:8000,https://server02:8000,https://server03:8000`.

I tried using a join:

```
set_fact:
  fact2: "{{ fact1|join(':8000,') }}"
```

which partly worked but it left the last server without a port.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Solution**

```
set_fact:
  fact2: "{{ fact1 | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', 'https://\\1:8000') | join(',') }}"
```

**Explanation**

1. [`map` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#map) applies a filter (`regex_replace`) to individual elements of the list;
2. [`regex_replace` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) (with the following regular expression) adds a `prefix` and `suffix` to a string;

   ```
   current_list | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', 'prefix\\1suffix')
   ```
3. [`join` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#join) converts the list to comma-delimited string in the output.

---

**Alternative**

Another possible solution (builds on what you already know) would be to use Jinja2 to directly for the target string:

```
set_fact:
  fact2: "{{ 'https://' + fact1|join(':8000,https://') + ':8000' }}"
```

Comment: Beware that on some Python versions, `(.*)`will match the whole string and an empty string at the end, which means it will make two replacements: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters. We should use `^(.*)$` instead.

Comment: Excuse me, but shouldn't that be `\1` instead of `\\1` there?

Answer (score 5):

Also you can use ternary filter:

```
set_fact:
  fact2: "{% for it in fact1 %}https://{{ it }}:8000{{ loop.last | ternary('', ',') }}{% endfor %}"
```

Answer (score 0):

i have this list of inventory i want to do like this
['servers']
server01
server02
server03
server04
in this example I want:
https://server01:8000;https://server02:8000],https://server03:8000;https://server04:8000]