# Looping through dictionary values inside Ansible playbook

Tags: dictionary, ansible, config, var

I have an Ansible playbook that sets up Splunk cluster, one of the commands adds a Server List of cluster members,

```
- name: search head init & set CAPTAIN 
  block: 
    - command: splunk init shcluster-config -auth admin:changeme \
          -mgmt_uri "https://{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:8089" \
          -replication_port 8090 -conf_deploy_fetch_url https://{{ deployer_ip }}:8089 -secret {{ cluster['secret'] }}
      # set captain
    - debug: msg='setting captain'
    - command: splunk bootstrap shcluster-captain \
              -servers_list "10.185.20.156:8089, 10.185.20.160:8089, 10.185.20.161:8089" -auth admin:changeme
```

I have all my config vars set inside a file, and thats where Im getting them from (for example, `cluster['secret']`), the `config.yaml` varfile looks like this,

```
# Cluster Config
cluster:
  secret: abracadabra  # secret key
  app_name: cluster  # adds a custom Splunk App for Cluster config
  members:
    mrxsplunksh01: 10.185.20.156
    mrxsplunksh02: 10.185.20.160 
    mrxsplunksh03: 10.185.20.161
```

I cant figure out how to parse/loop the cluster['members'] dictionary to get the IP of each cluster member, so I dont have to do this part manually,

```
  - command: splunk bootstrap shcluster-captain \
                  -servers_list "10.185.20.156:8089, 10.185.20.160:8089, 10.185.20.161:8089" -auth admin:changeme
```

I tried `with_items` and `with_dict` and I can't get it to parse each element correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loops to achieve this.

- Firstly, you can get a list of dictionary values with Python [`values()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values):

  ```
  cluster.members.values()
  ```
- Then you need to modify individual elements of the list like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47048066/2947502):

  ```
  map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\1:8089')
  ```
- Finally, you need to convert the list to a string, splitting the elements with `,`:

  ```
  join(', ')
  ```

---

Combined:

```
- servers_list "{{ cluster.members.values() | map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '\\1:8089') | join(', ') }}" -auth admin:changeme
```

<sup>I’m answering from phone now, so I have not verified the exact outcome, or typos yet.</sup>

<sup>And you should quote the whole argument to the `command` if it was written in one line. I’m not sure if YAML requires it with `\`, or if splitting this way is correct at all.</sup>